# Newton's method finding a specific point

Tags: calculus

For a given function is there a general procedure to find an initial value for $x_1$ such that Newton's method bounces back and forth between two values forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For function $f(x)$ and $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac1{f'(x_n)}$, simply set $ x_n = x_{n+2}$, which yields $x =\left(x-\frac1{f'(x)}\right)-\frac1{f'\left(x-\frac1{f'(x)}\right)}.$ Solve for $x$ and you have all points that either oscillate between two values or remain stationary. Such points are not guaranteed to exist for all $f$.

In fact, if you set $x_n=x_{n+k}$ with any $k$ and solve for $x$, the value will pass through at most $k$ points before arriving back at the original $x$.